# Will the shared sheets be removed if I my account is deleted in company's gsuite?

Tags: google-sheets, google-account

The company that I work on uses some neuralgic spreadsheets that I created and shared with my team. I am the owner of them.

If my account is deleted from company's owner (for various legitimate reasons), would these sheets be lost or the team will still have access to them?

All the sheets are saved to a shared folder that is shared using my coleagues emails. The sheets is shared within google suite towards accounts that belong to the same organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation: *Depending on your organization's Google account: All of a user's data is deleted, unless you transfer it to another user[...]* Obviously deletion of data is not a desirable outcome but there are options.

Your administrator needs to familiarise themselves with the various options and issues. Start with [Google Workspace admin Help](https://support.google.com/a#topic=2425090) and perhaps focus on [Delete or suspend users](https://support.google.com/a/topic/4388359?hl=en&ref_topic=2425090)

I don't suggest that this is a full/complete list but consider:

- [Delete or remove a user from your organization](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33314)
- [Manage former employees and their data](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9048836)
- [Maintain data security after an employee leaves](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6329207)